# Redirection problem with Angular AuthGuard

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I'm trying to redirect users to a certain route if they are already logged in on the platform (I check this using cookies) when they access my website's base url. 
The expected behaviour is this:

- User goes to `www.example.com`.
- If he is already logged in, redirect to `www.example.com/my-account`.
- If not, go to `www.example.com`.

I tried to use CanActivate with the following code:

```
canActivate() {
this.authService.checkStatus()
.subscribe(
  resp => {
   this.allowed = resp['isValid'];
  },
  error => {
    this.allowed = false;
  }
);

if(this.allowed) {
  this.router.navigate(['/my-account']);
  return true;
}
 return false;
}
```

The problem is that if the user is not logged in it will show a white page because the component will not load.

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the answer just suggestion**

Basucally it is based on scope of your app. If your app has small scope, just load all data when app starts. If scope is big then go with lazy loading.

The thing is you have load basic all components which are used first by the user.

E.x: `Login , registration , forgot`

Comment: Sorry, but how is that solving my problem? I'm new to angular.

Comment: lazy loading mean you load components in bunch of few components. which are used simultaneously by user in you app.

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/